# Intermittently functional Twitter Bootstrap in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

The first one is an attempt to center some text. Even if you replace the offset from 2 to, say, 5, it doesn't move the text to any different position.

[image]

Here you can see a situation where all I did is change the html text in the first image to something with a different Bootstrap style - in this case, it's the warning stuff. This all works fine. I got the offset and grid stuff straight from the Bootstrap docs - what's going on? Thanks

[image]

Edit - the app's on Github here: https://github.com/MaxPleaner/mystery

Edit - I realize that I made a mistake by using col-md in the above example and expecting the style to work on all screen sizes. However, I tried changing it to col-xs and it doesn't work either. See below.

[image]

Comment: - col-xs tells the columns not to stack and the columns will remain side-by-side. While col-md will stack the columns one-on-top of the other.

Comment: Also Twitter bootstrap uses a lot of different files to work. Do you have all of the the JS and css files included? What does your application.css and application.html.erb file look like?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview

Comment: @RussellKompinski i linked to the github file. Chedk out the first commit. The view code is in  a "homepage" folder in app/views.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that gem from thomas Mcdonald before. According to that you just need to bundle install and restart rails server for assets to be available.

**I use the gem:**

```
      gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails', :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails', :branch => '3.0.0'
```

I also noticed that you didn't include bootstrap in your application.js file, which in my case I  used -

```
     //= require twitter/bootstrap
```

I see that you have require bootstrap in your application.css.scss file and I assume your gem is serving the assets that you need and will be using the homepage.css.scss in the tree to override bootstrap. So that should be okay.

You do seem to have access to the grid so it seems to be loading bootstrap fine.

**As for your column issue:**

col-xs tells the columns not to stack and the columns will remain side-by-side. They still behave responsive as far as conforming to device size via media query. col-md will stack the columns one-on-top of the other.

Look more into the the examples out there. You're working with a 12 column grid system. Try pasting over some sample code from examples to if those shows up correctly.